# Cant read with a boost C++ client from a java server

Tags: java, c++, boost, client, server

I am trying to create a simple messaging application, using a C++ client and a Java server.

It seems I can't get around because the C++ client fails to get information from the Java server, yet I can't track down the problem.

I have tried connecting with a Java client to the Java server and it works well.

I have tried connecting with the C++ Client to a simple C++ echo server I made for this purpose, and everything is going well (it reads the information).

I have tried connecting with the java client to the c++ echo server and it works well.

Keep in mind that the Java server get all the information from the client, and is responding (eg: when I try to Log in, the server gets it, logs me in, and "sends" a http response setting the cookie and displaying a welcome message, but the client never gets it).

Here is the java code which send the reply:

```
        while ((msg = tokenizer.nextMessage()) != null)
    {
        System.out.println("Received \"" + msg + "\" from client");
        String response = (String)protocol.processMessage(msg);
        System.out.println(response); // used for testing
        if (response != null)
        {

            clientSocket.getOutputStream().write(response.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            //the Out below this line is being initialized on connection, just put it here for you to read
            //Also the out.println(response) doesn't work as well, those are 2 attempts i have made
            //out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8"), true);
            //out.println(response);

        }

        if (protocol.isEnd(msg))
        {
            break;
        }

    }
```

Here is the client side code (C++):

```
        //while (_socket.available() == 0){
    //  boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(10));
    //  std::cout << "test";
    //}
    char reply[max_length];
    size_t reply_length = boost::asio::read(_socket,boost::asio::buffer(reply,10));
    //size_t reply_length = boost::asio::read(_socket, boost::asio::buffer(reply, _socket.available()));
    std::cout << "Reply is:\n";
    std::cout.write(reply, reply_length);
    std::cout << "\n";
```

Note that the while above in the start of the code is used in order to wait for the response after each sent message, I have tried replacing it with a longer sleep time so I wont have to check the size of the incoming buffer, as you can see just after it I am trying to read a buffer the size of 10, just from testing, and i put the "real" read line in a comment just after it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

EDIT - Forgot to mention that if I close the socket after sending the information passes, but doing so fails the purpose, as I am trying to keep the socket open until the client performs a log out.

EDIT #2- I have tried a diffrent method of reading, by using a delimiter char and reaing the buffer 1 char at the time, it just get stuck blocking with the empty buffer.

Here is the code for the second type of reading which i have tried:

```
std::string respone = "";
    char ch='0';
    boost::system::error_code error;
    try {
        while(!error && ch!='$'){
            size_t tmp=0;

            try {
                std::cout << "going to read:";
                tmp = _socket.read_some(boost::asio::buffer(&ch + tmp, 1 - tmp), error);
                std::cout << "finish reading 1 char";

                if (error)
                    throw boost::system::system_error(error);
            }
            catch (std::exception& e) {
                std::cerr << "recv failed (Error: " << e.what() << ')' << std::endl;

            }
            respone.append(1, ch);
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit silly, but apparntly my anti virus was blocking all the packets from the java server (and not the c++  for some reason), turning  it off solved every thing.